# Annotation processing with kotlin-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

So i have maven project with 2 modules.

Root pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>kashier</groupId>
<artifactId>Kashier</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>AnnotationProcessing</module>
    <module>TestProject</module>
</modules>
```

And the pom.xml for AnnotationProcessing module :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<parent>
    <groupId>kashier</groupId>
    <artifactId>Kashier</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>AnnotationProcessing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.0.3</kotlin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now everything works fine only if i manually create javax.annotation.processing.Processor file in resources directory.
That means that auto-service is not working and the question is: how do i make it work?

Also i tried to make the same project with java and it works. So i think that the problem is in kotlin-maven-plugin.

Source code of the project can be found [here](https://github.com/mitya1337/Kashier)

Comment: Your dependency on `auto-service` is optional yet apparently your code does not work without it. So why is it optional then?

Comment: @OlegSklyar it's not working even if i remove optional filed. I added it because in `auto-service` documentation they say that i need to make it optional.

Answer (score 1):

auto-service is using annotation processor too so you have to add into your kotlin-maven-plugin (before compile section) this:

```
<execution>
    <id>kapt</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>kapt</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <!-- Specify your annotation processors here. -->
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
                <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-rc4</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```